# Shutdown of camel routes with time consuming process

Tags: apache-camel, shutdown

We have a camel route that looks at a file and processes potentially hundreds of records on this file, almost like a batch routine (yet there will only be one message in camel). Thus the message will take potentially minutes or maybe hours to complete. We want to shut down the queue once this message (and any others waiting) are complete.

We have the following to consider:

The shutdown strategy defines the time to wait for a route to stop before a forced shutdown

```
<bean id="shutdown" class="org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy"> 
 <property name="timeout" value="#[bpf.defaultShutdownStrategy.timeout]"/>
</bean>
```

The route has a parameter shutdownRunningTask="CompleteAllTasks" which should wait untill all messages processed.

Not sure which is going to take presidence as the timeout once exceeded is not graceful, it will force shutdown and for our scneario it is likely we will exceed a timeout, as we cannot predict how long processing will take.

Any ideas/considerations?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the [onCompletion](http://camel.apache.org/oncompletion.html) functionality. It adds a new route in a separated thread when the Exchange is complete.

Here is some examples from the Camel documentation:

**Java DSL**

```
// define a global on completion that is invoked when the exchange is complete
onCompletion().to("log:global").to("mock:sync");

from("direct:start")
    .process(new MyProcessor())
    .to("mock:result");
```

**XML DSL**

```
<!-- this is a global onCompletion route that is invoke when any exchange is complete
     as a kind of after callback -->
<onCompletion>
    <to uri="log:global"/>
    <to uri="mock:sync"/>
</onCompletion>

<route>
    <from uri="direct:start"/>
    <process ref="myProcessor"/>
    <to uri="mock:result"/>
</route>
```

Then, here is [documentation](http://camel.apache.org/how-can-i-stop-a-route-from-a-route.html) on **how to stop a route** in Camel.